# Unable to execute Snowball stemming functions in PHP7

Tags: php

I have multiple versions of PHP in my server i need to enable support for stemming in php7 i have compiled php7 from source code and php 5.6 from package manager i am able to get access to php stem functions in php5.6 but not been able to handle stem functions in php7

> [root@ValidationDB ~]# php7 -f stem.php 
>   PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: stem: Unable to initialize module
>   Module compiled with module API=20121212
>   PHP    compiled with module API=20151012
>   These options need to match
>    in Unknown on line 0
>   Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function stem_english() in /root/stem.php:3
>   Stack trace:
>   0 {main}thrown in /root/stem.php on line 3

Comment: Looks like your installing the wrong version of the module, which was compiled using VC12 when your php was compiled using VC15. You would need to compile both.

Comment: You mean to say i need to uninstall php5.6 and php7 and then reinstall it from from source code ?